# How do I put futures in a container?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm trying to put the futures generated by async in a vector, so I don't have to do something like:

```
auto f1 = async(....);
auto f2 = async(....);
...
f1.get();
f2.get();
...
```

The compilation error I am receiving with this code is "Call to deleted constructor of 'std::_1::future". Can anyone help me with how to do this properly. Not sure about copying the future's into the vector either.

```
void AudioAnalyzer::retrieve()
{
    deque<shared_ptr<AudioAnalysis>>tempData(data);
    vector<future<void>> futures;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i)
    {
        auto f = async(bind(&AudioAnalyzer::analysisThread, this, _1), ref(tempData));
        futures.push_back(f);
    }

    for (auto& f : futures)
    {
        f.get();
    }

}

void AudioAnalyzer::analysisThread(deque<shared_ptr<AudioAnalysis>>& aq )
{

    while (true)
    {
        m.lock();
        if (aq.size() == 0)
        {
            m.unlock();
            break;
        }
        auto aa = aq.front();
        aq.pop_front();
        m.unlock();

        if (false) //testing
        {
            retrieveFromDb(aa);
        }
        else
        {
            analyzeAudio(aa);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Futures are not copyable, but they are move-copyable. You need to move them into the container:

```
futures.push_back(std::move(f));
```

Here, `std::move(f)` looks like an rvalue, resulting in the right [`std::vector<future<void>>::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) overload being selected.

Comment: Note that you may also use directly `futures.push_back(async(..));`.

Comment: How do you access the futures? `futures[i]` still calls the copy constructor.

Comment: @ziyuang `futures[i]` is an lvalue reference, so a copy is only made if you use it to initialise a new object. You can say `futures[i].whatever()`, or, if you are in a scope where you are sure the reference won't get invalidated, `auto& f = futures[i]; f.whatever();` for example.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using C++11, you can also use the new `emplace_back` operator of std::vector like so:

```
futures.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, f));
```

This will construct the `std::future` object in-place (directly into the std::vector) and thus avoid having to copy or move the future.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back

Comment: Since `std::async` returns a `std::future` instance, doesn't that mean `emplace_back` simply moves it in, just as `push_back` would? I know that `emplace_back` will construct instances in place if you pass it constructor arguments for the type that the vector is holding, but when passing it an existing object it appears to invoke the move constructor.