# c++ How do I .get() std::future out of a vector?

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector

This is for my c++ class final project.  I am trying to use std::future for the first time, and need some help.  You can see all of my code here: https://github.com/AdamJHowell/3370-FinalProject

Here is the signature of the function that I am trying to get a future from:

```
        std::vector<stockDay> FuturesSmaEma( std::size_t numP, std::vector<stockDay> &inputVector );
```

I have tried multiple solutions in this block:

```
        std::vector<std::future<std::vector<stockDay> > > futureSpawnVector;    // A vector of futures that we are spawning.
        std::vector<std::vector<stockDay> > futureResultsVector;                // A vector of futures return values.

        for( auto inputVector : VectorOfStockDayVectors ){
            futureSpawnVector.push_back( std::move( std::async( FuturesSmaEma, numPArray[0], inputVector ) ) );
        }

        for each ( auto &var in futureSpawnVector ){
            var.wait();
        }
        for each ( auto &var in futureSpawnVector ){
            // Put the future from that into our futureResultsVector.
            futureResultsVector.push_back( var ); // Produces Error C2280 'std::future<std::vector<stockDay,std::allocator<_Ty>>>::future(const std::future<std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function   3370-FinalProject   f:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xmemory0 637
            futureResultsVector.push_back( std::move( var ) ); // Produces Error C2664 'void std::vector<std::vector<stockDay,std::allocator<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>>>::push_back(const std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>> &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const std::future<std::vector<stockDay,std::allocator<_Ty>>>' to 'std::vector<stockDay,std::allocator<_Ty>> &&' main.cpp    179std::allocator<std::vector<stockDay, std::allocator<stockDay>>>>

            futureResultsVector.push_back( var.get() );
            futureResultsVector.push_back( std::move( var.get() ) );

            auto tempStuff = var.get(); // Produces Error C2662 'std::vector<stockDay,std::allocator<_Ty>> std::future<std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>>::get(void)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const std::future<std::vector<stockDay,std::allocator<_Ty>>>' to 'std::future<std::vector<stockDay,std::allocator<_Ty>>> &'
            std::cout << "futureSpawnVector now has " << tempStuff.size() << " elements." << std::endl;
            std::cout << tempStuff[0].date << " ema: " << tempStuff[0].ema << std::endl;

            std::cout << var.get().at( 0 ).date << " ema: " << var.get()[0].ema << std::endl; // Desperate attempt to understand what is going on here.

            std::vector<std::future<std::vector<stockDay> > > smaVector42;
            futureResultsVector.push_back( smaVector42 ); // Produces Error (active) no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=std::future<std::vector<stockDay, std::allocator<stockDay>>>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::future<std::vector<stockDay, std::allocator<stockDay>>>>]" matches the argument list
        }
```

I expected this block to create a vector of results from those threads.  What am I doing wrong?

I have also looked here: [How do I put futures in a container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23458124/how-do-i-put-futures-in-a-container)

I have a function that returns a vector of "stockDay" class objects.  Each element in the vector represents the stock data for one day.

I need to run this function 15 times (on five stocks over 3 periods).  So I want to thread that function, and get the returned vector.

I can easily create a single future, wait() for the thread, and get() the resulting vector.  However, I want to create a vector of those futures.  If I understand this correctly, this will be a vector of futures, each of which will be a vector of "stockDay" class objects.

I seem to have that part working correctly.  The vector .size() shows the correct number of elements (five right now for testing).

I loop through that vector, and perform a .wait() on each element.  That works as well.

Now I want to .push_back() each future's .get() into another vector.  This is not working for me.

I know you want me to give you the exact error message, but I've tried about a dozen different solutions, and they all produce slightly different errors.

Lines 174 through 187 is where the errors occur.  I have them commented out and different attempts separated from each other.

I understand the code shown here: https://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/10/17/cpp-11-async-tutorial/

You will see an example from that tutorial in my code on lines 135 to 148.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for **specific** questions. Don't post a link to your whole GitHub project, give a general idea of what the problem is and then ask how to fix it - instead, put as much relevant code as you can in the question (but still as little code as you can while including all the relevant code), the specific error you get from compiling this code, and so on. (Also, I don't see a question in the question body, only in the title)

Comment: If you're not sure what you need to say, a useful template is: 1) What did I do? 2) What did I expect/want to happen? 3) What actually happened?

Comment: @immibis Last time I posted a question, I cleaned up my code as best I could and posted the relevant parts.  I was lambasted for not including all of my code.  So this time, I tried to do better, and now I'm being told kind of the opposite.  Both times resulted in my question being downvoted and a loss of reputation.  It is quite frustrating.

Comment: Post **complete** code (not just the "relevant" parts, because if you definitely knew what was relevant you wouldn't need to ask the question), but reduce the irrelevant clutter to make it **minimal** (not a link to a github project). Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The std::move is redundant here: `futureSpawnVector.push_back( std::move( std::async( FuturesSmaEma, ...)`. The function returns by value, so it will be moved automatically, calling std::move on it does nothing except complicate the code.

Comment: What's this `for each (auto& var in cont)` nonsense in your code? That isn't C++ ... what are "each" and "in" ?!

Comment: Jonathan, I think you found it!  The Visual Studio editor allows that type of for loop, but apparently the VS compiler does not.  So far, it works!  Thank you so much!

Comment: It turns out this was due to Microsoft's proposed https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI initiative.  Their editor supports  'for each (auto& var in container)', but their compiler does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to Microsoft's C++/CLI (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI).  Visual Studio 2015 allows for loops like this...

```
for each( auto var in container )
```

...but it will not compile with certain types, such as a vector of futures.

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to `push_back()` a `future`, that is your error because `future` has no copy constructor and so an existing one cannot be pushed back.

You should instead create a `vector<future>` container and `push_back()` `std::async` operations like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <future>

using namespace std;

int func(int arg, int arg2)
{
    return arg + arg2;
}

int main()
{
    vector<future<int>> tasks;
    future<int> moveThis;

    tasks.push_back(async(func, 1, 2));
}
```

You could also `push_back()` a future object by moving it using `std::move()`:

```
tasks.push_back(std::move(moveThis));
```

Then getting the answer from that future should be as simple as:

```
int temp = tasks[0].get();
```

Note: Once you use `get()`, the future object becomes invalid and you cannot `get()` it a second time.

Comment: I tried that exact syntax.  Getting the futures into the vector is not my problem, getting the results out of that vector and into another vector is my problem.
I even tried std::move() to put the future into the vector.  It also works, but does not help me get the results out.

Comment: @Stephen, it's not necessary to insert the result of the `async` call directly, you can use `std::move` to insert a future (which will move it, not copy it). And calling `get()` dos not destroy the future, it makes it invalid. That's not the same. You can move-assign another future to it and re-use it, which you couldn't do if it was destroyed.

Comment: Thank you, I changed my answer so that I am not spreading false information.

Comment: The update is wrong, you don't use std::move on pointers, it should be `std::move(moveThis)` not `std::move(&moveThis)`

Answer (score 5):

> `futureResultsVector.push_back( var ); // Produces Error`

You can't copy a `future`, you need to move it:

```
futureResultsVector.push_back( std::move(var) );
```

> `auto tempStuff = var.get(); // Produces Error`

The error means that `var` is a const object, and you can't get the result out of a const future. You need to fix the code so it doesn't access it in a const context.

> `futureResultsVector.push_back( smaVector42 ); // Produces Error`

You're trying to push a vector into a vector. That obviously won't work.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan.  The updated code:  
futureResultsVector.push_back( std::move( var ) ); produces this error:
Error (active) no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=std::vector<stockDay, std::allocator<stockDay>>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::vector<stockDay, std::allocator<stockDay>>>]" matches the argument list main.cpp 179 argument types are: (std::future<std::vector<stockDay, std::allocator<stockDay>>>) object type is: std::vector<std::vector<stockDay, std::allocator<stockDay>>, std::allocator<std::vector<stockDay, std::allocator<stockDay>>>>

Comment: Did you read the error? It's telling you you're trying to push a `future<vector<stockDay>>` into a `vector<vector<stockDay>>` ... which means you lied about the type of `futureResultsVector` in the code you showed above. `futureResultsVector.push_back( std::move(var.get()) )` should work, but maybe you should stop and think about what you're actually trying to do, and ensure it makes sense.

Comment: I still do not have this working.  Will you help me validate my logic please?
The function that I am threading returns a vector of 'stockDay' class objects.
So when I get a future from async, it will be a future containing a vector that contains multiple 'stockDay' objects.
Am I correct so far?
When I put that future into a vector, the result will be: a vector of futures, that each contain a vector of 'stockDay' objects.
Am I correct at this point?
If so, I believe that 'futureSpawnVector' should be of type 'std::vector<std::future<std::vector<stockDay> > >'.
Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But that's not where the errors are coming from, is it? The error message says that future**Result**Vector is a `vector<vector<stockDay>>`, which is not the same. If you want to move futures from `futureSpawnVector` to `futureResultVector` then they should be the same type. Your error message says they are not the same type. Fix that.

Comment: Once you have the types correct, and you fix the const-ness of futureSpawnVector, you can move everything from one vector to the other in a single operation with: `futureResultVector.insert( std::move_iterator(futureSpawnVector.begin()), std::move_iterator(futureSpawnVector.end()) );`

Comment: So you have two problems: the type of futureResultVector (which is **not* what you claimed it was in the question!) and the fact that futureSpawnVector is const when you try to iterate over it.

Comment: I'm sorry that it does not match type in the question.  I was not being malicious, and I appreciate your help.  How do I make futureSpawnVector not-const?  Also, I'm not trying to copy the vector, I'm trying to get the return value from the futures in futureSpawnVector to futureResultsVector.  Is that even possible?

Comment: _"I'm trying to get the return value from the futures in futureSpawnVector to futureResultsVector"_ that's not what your code was doing though, so it's no wonder that you couldn't make it work, and your question was confusing and hard to answer, even without the misinformation about what types you're using. I assume the vector was const because of the non-standard "for each (... in ...)" junk. To put the return value from the futures use `futureResultsVector.push_back( std::move(var.get()) )` (which I already said above several hours ago).

Answer (score 0):

To put future into the vector, using std::future.push_back(), as:

```
std::vector<std::future<T>> futures[num_blocks - 1];
futures[i].push_back(SOMETHING_FUTURE);
```

Or get future from the vector, using (*std::future.begin()).get(), but only once .get() could use. As:

```
T result =(*futures[i].begin()).get();
```

May this helps, either maybe perhaps a segmentation fault. Peace!